# How to optimize filtering a database of more than 400K rows based on a list?

Tags: pandas, database, dataframe, filter

I'm trying to filter a huge database of 400 000 rows based on one column called 'description'

To filter this dataframe, I'm trying to only filter the rows where certains words are within the description column. My search list is composed of 2000 strings.

My approach for now is very simple :

```
df[df['description'].str.contains('|'.join(search_list), case=False)]
```

it's taking forever. How can I optimize this?

Comment: The dataframe gets it's data from a database ?  Why not filter iusing the capabilities of that database ?

Comment: Also, it might sometimes be faster to just do an inner join instead of using str.contains